# knockout observableArray elements don't update view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

With knockoutjs I have an observable array and the child elements are also observable.  The observable array is bound through a foreach.  When i update an element of the array, the view isn't updated.

Why is that?

I have a jsfiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/axUm6/7/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: someList">
    <li>
        <div style="float: left" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;" class="update">update</div>
    </li>   
</ul>

vmTemplate = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.someList = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.someList.push(ko.observable({name: 'test 1'}));
        self.someList.push(ko.observable({name: 'test 2'}));        

        $(document).on('click', '.update', function () {
            var itemToUpdate = ko.dataFor(this);
            self.alertTheList();
            itemToUpdate.name = 'test 3';            
            self.alertTheList();
            self.someList.valueHasMutated();
        }); //on click
    }; //init

    self.alertTheList=function(){
        var message='';
        for(var i=0;i<self.someList().length;i++){
            message+=self.someList()[i]().name;
        }
        alert(message);        
    };//alertTheList
};

var vm = new vmTemplate();
vm.init();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: That's not how it's supposed to work. You should not have any dependency on the view inside the view model, so no jQuery event handlers, for starters. Use the `click` binding. Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/nru85/

Comment: I have updated my code to be similar to @Alexander's, which uses the correct event binding.  What do you mean 'for starters'  is there something else wrong?  Bear in mind this was a sample to show my problem so the alert's, for example, were just to help with debugging.

Comment: Well, I consider the use of `ko.dataFor()` unclean in KO view models, but it's connected to the the point that you have a dependency on the view. The goal must be to have a view model without external dependencies. (If you need to use jQuery, do so in custom bindings, and only there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ItemViewModel with observable properties instead self.someList.push(ko.observable(...)). Look [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xxTBB/2/). Also, i've change jQuery click event handler on knockout binding.

Html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: someList">
    <li>
        <div style="float: left" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;" class="update" data-bind="click: $parent.updateName">update</div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

ViewModel:

```
ItemViewModel = function(val) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(val);
}

vmTemplate = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.someList = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.someList.push(new ItemViewModel('test 1'));
        self.someList.push(new ItemViewModel('test 2'));        
    }; //init

    self.updateName = function(item) {
        self.alertTheList();
        item.name('test 3');            
        self.alertTheList();
    }; //on click

    self.alertTheList=function(){
        var message='';
        for(var i=0;i<self.someList().length;i++){
            message+=self.someList()[i].name();
        }
        alert(message);        
    };//alertTheList
};

var vm = new vmTemplate();
vm.init();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```